# Python Won't write to text file

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, logging

Im am trying to write ip address from a file to another file if they occur more than 30 times using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#open the auth.log file
myFile = open('auth.log','r') 

myTxtFile = open('blacklist2.txt','w') #open the Security_Test.txt for writing later

myTxtFile.write('The IP Addresses with more than 30 Attacks are:\n') #prints out a line of text ready for the outcome

ip_attacks = {}
count_attacks = 0

#go through each line of the file and return it to the variable line
for line in myFile.readlines():

    #get the IP address
    #we are working backwards to avoid the difference of the length of the NT logs
    attack_ip = list_of_line[-4]
    attack_ip_list= attack_ip.split('port')
    attack_address = attack_ip_list[0]
    if 'Failed password for' in line:
        #print '\'',attack_address,'\''
        if ip_attacks.has_key(attack_address):
            count_attacks = ip_attacks[attack_address]
            count_attacks = count_attacks +1
            ip_attacks[attack_address] = count_attacks
            #zero out the temporary counter as a precaution
            count_attacks =0 
        else:
            ip_attacks[attack_address] = 1
        if count_attacks > 30:
            myTxtFile.write(ip_attacks)
```

But it will not write to the text file, the only thing the does write to the text file is the first line 'The IP Addresses with more than 30 Attacks are:' is there anything i am doing wrong here which is not allowing me to write the ip_address from the file to another file??

**Example Lines From Log File:**

```
Feb  5 08:25:47 j4-be02 sshd[2130]: Failed password for root from 5.199.133.223 port 50259 ssh2
Feb  5 08:25:55 j4-be02 sshd[2133]: Failed password for root from 5.199.133.223 port 57329 ssh2
```

Comment: seems your code never go by `if count_attacks > 30:` branch

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong because you reset `count_attacks` to zero. I believe you want your if statement to be:

```python
if ip_attacks[attack_address] > 30:
        myTxtFile.write(ip_attacks)
```

instead of:

```python
if count_attacks > 30:
        myTxtFile.write(ip_attacks)
```

**EDIT:**
Btw. I believe that these 3 lines:

```python
count_attacks = ip_attacks[attack_address]
count_attacks = count_attacks +1
ip_attacks[attack_address] = count_attacks
```

can be replaced with:

```python
ip_attacks[attack_address] += 1
```

Edit: The complete solution to the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from collections import defaultdict
#open the auth.log file
myFile = open('auth.log','r') 

myTxtFile = open('blacklist2.txt','w') #open the Security_Test.txt for writing later

myTxtFile.write('The IP Addresses with more than 30 Attacks are:\n') #prints out a line of text ready for the outcome

ip_attacks = defaultdict(int)
count_attacks = 0

#go through each line of the file and return it to the variable line
for line in myFile.readlines():

#get the IP address
#we are working backwards to avoid the difference of the length of the NT logs
attack_ip = list_of_line[-4]
attack_ip_list= attack_ip.split('port')
attack_address = attack_ip_list[0]
if 'Failed password for' in line:
    #print '\'',attack_address,'\''
    ip_attacks[attack_address] += 1


for key, value in ip_attacks.iteritems():
    if value > 30:
        myTxtFile.write(key)
```

Comment: I keep getting an error on this line myTxtFile.write(ip_attacks)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: ip_attacks is a dictionary. You need to pass strings or a character bufffer object to the write() function.

Comment: I've got it now to work but it still doesn't write what i want to the text file it is writing every IP to the file where it should only state 2-3 IP addresses

Comment: yes i replaced the count_attacks = 0 to the new if statement and replaced the 3 lines with the new line

Comment: no, you should not replace count_attacks = 0 with the if statement. You should replace your old if statement: if count_attacks > 30:
            myTxtFile.write(ip_attacks) with the new one. sorry if this was not clear. I edited my answer to be more clear.

Comment: it is still doing the same thing

Comment: its printing out around 300 lines of this:  {'1.234.51.243': 15, '83.212.110.234': 57, '62.45.87.113': 1, '211.167.103.172': 172, '85.17.188.70': 4}

{'1.234.51.243': 15, '83.212.110.234': 58, '62.45.87.113': 1, '211.167.103.172': 172, '85.17.188.70': 4}

{'83.212.110.234': 58, '5.199.133.223': 31, '192.64.114.62': 24, '1.234.51.243': 15, '62.45.87.113': 1, '211.167.103.172': 172, '61.142.106.34': 4, '85.17.188.70': 6}

{'83.212.110.234': 58, '5.199.133.223': 32, '192.64.114.62': 24, '1.234.51.243': 15, '62.45.87.113': 1, '211.167.103.172': 172, '61.142.106.34': 4, '85.17.188.70': 6}

Comment: You need to debug your code, it's hard to tell whats wrong. Take a look at your for loop - I believe der is another error in there.... for line in myFile.readlines():  -> you don't use the line variable anywhere in your code.... and where does this variable come from?

Comment: i do I'm looking for if 'Failed password for' in line: first as thats where the IP Address are

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106148/discussion-between-daniel-and-maecky).

Comment: Did you close the file object at the end of your code?